# How to scale a variable when not knowing the maximum

Tags: dataset, rnn, normalization, feature-scaling

I have a dataset with different features where some of them are not categorical, so they need to be scaled or normalized (especially the target).

However, normalizing between 0-1 for instance means that the variable maximum value will be equal to one, and the mean to 0.

Now if I receive a new example never seen before, and this example has a value higher than the max of the training examples, how should this value be normalized ?

**EDIT**

As an example. If my maximum value is 150, it will be scaled to 1.0. Now if I receive a new example, with a value equal to 320, how should it be scaled ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we apply normalization to test data as well?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27615/should-we-apply-normalization-to-test-data-as-well)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'not knowing the maximum'? If it's a case of missing values, you should handle imputation first or discard those records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model works in production, you should **not** retransform your scaler, you should transform new example like 150 is still the maximum value. (It will give you higher than 1, so its a bit problematic but possible solution is below)
However you can still label those example as outlier.

Possible solution for that case: If you have high number of outliers/leverages, you should consider **tree ensembles and/or regularized models**.

If your predictor is not on production, just add those examples to your train set and fit again since your sample in the first training would be different than the reality.